# Why keep two variables for one content in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

In C#, I notice that many coders do something like the following:

```
class X
{
    private int test_;

    public int test
    {
        get { return test_; }
        set { if (test_ != value) test_ = value; }
    }
}
```

My question is why keep a private, and a public variable for the same content?

Why did we not do this instead?

```
class X
{
    public int test
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

I mean, we are changing the private variable within anyway. What is the point of not using a single public variable instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
class X
{
    public int test
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

...is a direct equivalent for this:

```
class X
{
    private int test_;

    public int test
    {
        get { return test_; }
        set { test_ = value; }
    }
}
```

The first example is an auto-implemented property. The C# compiler automatically produces the second example when you compile.

Now, the code you presented first though had this line:

```
set { if (test_ != value) test_ = value; }
```

You'll notice that it's doing something different to the auto-property equivalent code. And that's where the difference lies in these two approaches.

When you use a backing field for your properties you can introduce specific rules that you need your code to follow.

For example, you might want to set the audio volume on a music app, so your code might be like this:

```
public class Music
{
    private int _volume = 7;

    public int Volume
    {
        get { return _volume; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 10)
            {
                _volume = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is common to have a private field variable when your property contains logic like this.

Comment: But if trivia: the compiler doesn’t guarantee anything regarding the name of the backing field for a given property. But, yeah, it pretty much always just has an underscore and such.

Comment: @cwharris - You're right. In fact it's often given an illegal C# name to avoid clashes with real variables.

Comment: @cwharris - In fact, the first example gives this as the backing field: `private int <test>k__BackingField;`. Yes, the `<test>` is part of the name - it's illegal C#, but perfectly fine for IL.

Comment: whow, I don’t remember it naming things that crazily. Then again, the last time I checked was over 5 years ago. Goes to show they were serious about no guarantees. Thanks, CLR via C#, for more interesting implementation details - even if ill never need to know any of them.

Answer (score 1):

These are not two variables. One is a field and other one is a property. A property is optional getter and setter methods in disguise.

Your proposal of the solution is in fact part of the language, called auto-implemented properties: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: Please define what "auto-implemented properties" are in your answer. Links should only be used to support content in your answer already.